# Is it possible to recover the reloaded file in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, recovery

So here's the deal, I was working on a file from a live server, I used WinSCP for downloading the file and I was working on it using Notepad++.

After hours of work on the file suddenly, a message showed up that I don't have enough memory on my PC's hard drive so I cannot save the file in Notepad++. Later on after a few seconds, somehow the message appeared "**This file has been overwritten, Do you want to reload?**"

Unfortunately, I pressed **OK** and the file was reloaded. (**The file was completely empty when reloaded**)

All of my work is gone, I know I should have taken the backup first.

Now, I am trying to get the older version of that file but it seems impossible in this specific situation.

I tried to find a solution of this mistake on google but I think that my file was erased from the Notepad++ Cache and Backup directory.

I found some useful suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/390204/how-to-restore-a-previous-version-of-file-in-notepad) and [here](http://buffernow.com/notepad-plus-crash-recover-your-lost-file/).

Tried finding the file in the backup directory of Notepad++ here 
**C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup**

but the reloaded file was there as backup (The empty one)

Due to my mistake, I lost my work today and I just want to put this question so if there's a solution everyone should know.

It will be so nice of you guys if someone could explain what happened with my file and if there's way to recover it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder of the file, see if there is a subfolder called nppBackup. Recently I've found sometimes the backup wasn't created in %AppData%/Notepad++/backup but it always seems to get created here, with the following file name format [original file name][date stamp]_[time stamp].bak